# Microsoft Access Error

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

Error: Invalid use of IS operator in query expression...

Here is the formatted SQL-Code [by poorsql.com](http://poorsql.com/)

```sql
TRANSFORM Sum(Jacksonville.[Lease Rent]) AS SumOfAmount

SELECT S.Unit
    ,S.[Floorplan]
    ,S.[Unit Designation]
    ,S.SQFT
    ,S.[Unit and Lease Status]
    ,S.NAME
    ,S.[Move-In and Move-Out]
    ,S.[Lease Start]
    ,S.[Lease End]
    ,S.[Market and Addl.]
    ,S.[Sub Journal]
    ,S.[Trans Code]
    ,S.[Lease Rent]
    ,S.[Charges and Credits]
FROM Jacksonville
    ,(
        SELECT Q.Id
            ,Val(DMax(“Id”, ”Jacksonville”, ”Id <= “ & Q.[Id] & “
                    AND Unit IS NOT Null”)) AS ParentId
        FROM Jacksonville AS Q
        ) AS T
    ,(
        SELECT Jacksonville.Id
            ,Jacksonville.Unit
            ,Jacksonville.[Floorplan]
            ,Jacksonville.[Unit Designation]
            ,Jacksonville.SQFT
            ,Jacksonville.[Unit and Lease Status]
            ,Jacksonville.NAME
            ,Jacksonville.[MoveIn and MoveOut]
            ,Jacksonville.[Lease Start]
            ,Jacksonville.[Lease End]
            ,Jacksonville.[Market and Addl]
            ,Jacksonville.[Sub Journal]
            ,Jacksonville.[Trans Code]
            ,Jacksonville.[Lease Rent]
            ,Jacksonville.[Charges and Credits]
        FROM Jacksonville
        WHERE Jacksonville.Unit IS NOT NULL
        ) AS S
WHERE Jacksonville.Id = [T].[Id]
    AND T.ParentId = [S].[Id]
GROUP BY T.ParentId
    ,S.Unit
    ,S.[Floorplan]
    ,S.[Unit Designation]
    ,S.SQFT
    ,S.[Unit and Lease Status]
    ,S.NAME
    ,S.[Move-In and Move-Out]
    ,S.[Lease Start]
    ,S.[Lease End]
    ,S.[Market and Addl.]
    ,S.[Sub Journal]
    ,S.[Trans Code]
    ,S.[Lease Rent]
    ,S.[Charges and Credits]
PIVOT Jacksonville.[Trans Code] IN (
        [“ADMIN HOUS”]
        ,”EXRENT”
        ,[”LHA RENT”]
        ,[”MK-PREMIUM LHA”]
        ,”RENT”
        ,”SUBRENT”
        ,”SUBSIDY”
        ,”UTAC”
        ,”UTILREIMB”
        ,”OFF / SOCIAL”
        );
```

This syntax works on my other one, but not here for some reason. Why is my IS statement wrong?
Not sure how to edit the query structure on here.

Comment: That doesn't look anything like a complete query, and you shouldn't be using any form of Domain function in a query (A domain function is a query after all effectively, and very inefficient if used within a query) , either use a sub query or aggregate query to a linked table.

Comment: are you actually using these "quote" characters in Access like `“Id”` seems like that is likely to cause some issues....Also this syntax doesn't make sense to me. This is clearly part of a larger query (I hope). Can you post it all?

Comment: Try: `NOT IS NULL' or `NOT Jacksonville.Unit IS NULL`.

Comment: NOT IS NULL results in a syntax error, NOT Jacksonville.Unit IS NULL results in the original error

Comment: The file format is Access 07. The Excel is .xlsx

Comment: When debugging a complex query with embedded SQL, you should always test embedded statements separately. Likewise for a Transform query, run the select query separately to debug issues before executing the transform. All this makes it easier to narrow down a problem. I have experienced Access refusing to recognize perfectly legitimate SQL in a transform query, even though it all works outside of the transform. My solution has often been to save the query(ies) separately, then do the transform on the saved queries, even if it means redundantly grouping and sorting before and in the transform.

Comment: Also, why do cross joins and then filtering in the WHERE clause?  It should be much more efficient and equivalent by doing INNER JOINS.

Comment: My best guess is the problem is the break you inserted here: `DMax(“Id”, ”Jacksonville”, ”Id <= “ & Q.[Id] & “
                    AND Unit IS NOT Null”)` is causing the trouble. While SQL is mostly whitespace insensitive, placing breaks in quoted strings can cause problems.

Comment: Just saw your comment "Excel is .xlsx".  What does Excel have to do with it?  If this is an important detail, then please edit your question and explain more detail there... not just in the comments.  Is this a linked query to an Excel sheet?  Are you trying to execute this query in VBA code from Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the "smart quotes" (from a copy-paste from Word?) with double-quotes:

```
,Val(DMax("Id", "Jacksonville", "Id <= " & Q.[Id] & "
                AND Unit IS NOT Null")) AS ParentId
```